# debug configurations tab in mars eclipse in ubuntu 16 not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin, remote-debugging

When I'm going to configure debugger in eclipse for my java application, I get this error.

[image: eclipse error]

It is working fine in ubuntu 14 , but in ubuntu 16 it creates this problem. What should I have to change in my eclipse settings to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like something got corrupted.  You should be using Neon anyway, download and install the newer version.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have java 1.7 for my project , I think neon does not work for java 7 , it work on java 8 .It it??

Comment: You need a Java 8 JDK/JRE to run Eclipse but can still target earlier versions for YOUR code.  If you absolutely want to remain with Mars I suggest downloading and re-installing.